# How to install GridDB Python Client module on Google Colab instance using pip?

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, griddb

I am trying to install the GridDB Python Client Library in Google Colab using the pip command as follows:

```
!pip install griddb-python-client
```

Once I executed the code the following error code was returned:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting griddb-python-client
  Downloading griddb_python_client-0.5.2.tar.gz (31 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: griddb-python-client
  Building wheel for griddb-python-client (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for griddb-python-client
  Running setup.py clean for griddb-python-client
Failed to build griddb-python-client
Installing collected packages: griddb-python-client
    Running setup.py install for griddb-python-client ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-p02oyjyo/griddb-python-client_4d5f55e3d8c74745b962c1746fdc7827/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-p02oyjyo/griddb-python-client_4d5f55e3d8c74745b962c1746fdc7827/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-zz5s4blp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7/griddb-python-client Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/griddb-python-client/ Build dependencies: SWIG, GridDB C Client.